# Calculate mean from range

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, range

Suppose we have data points like

[image]

How can we calculate mean from this dataset

Answer (score 1):

This Question has two interesting and somewhat similar parts. The first question is in the title
and the second is the question about the data table you provided.

**Title.**
Suppose the data are normal in particular, or symmetrical in general (provided that the population mean exists). Then it is
possible to get a reasonable estimate of $\mu$ as the *midrange,* which is halfway between the max and the min.

For example, if I take a sample of size $n = 100$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = 5),$ then let's compare the sample mean $\bar X$ (the *best* estimate of $\mu)$ with the sample midrange. [Notice that in R, `range` gives the max and min, not the range. Subtract (max - min) to get the true range and average (min+max)/2 to get the midrange.]

```
set.seed(810)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 5)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  38.71   46.71   49.51   50.13   53.62   63.91 

mean(x)
[1] 50.12619
range(x);  mean(range(x)) 
[1] 38.71067 63.91233
[1] 51.3115
```

For this sample, we know the population mean is $\mu=50$ (only because this
is a simulation), that the sample mean is $50.13$ and the midrange is $51.31.$

Many statistics books show that the standard deviation of the sample mean
is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$ which is $\sigma_{\bar X} = 5/\sqrt{100} = 0.50$ in our example.

By simulation of a million such samples, we can get a good approximation of
the standard deviation of the midrange: $1.52 > 0.50.$ Because the sample mean is a much less variable estimator than the midrange, we prefer to use the sample mean when possible.

```
set.seed(2020)
mr = replicate(10^6, mean(range(rnorm(100,50,5))))
sd(mr)
[1] 1.524349
```

Above I have answered the question suggested by the title of your question.

**Table.**
*However,* it your table, you don't have the true "range" of *anything.* You
have interval endpoints for income *categories.*

You might guess the
income of each subject in the list lies at the middle of his/her income
category. Then average those midpoints to estimate the population mean income. A similar method is often
used to estimate the mean of a histogram when only interval endpoints
and frequencies are available.

If you went to the trouble of making a histogram of subject incomes from
data in your table, then you could estimate the mean income of
the sampled subjects as $\bar X \approx \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^K f_im_i,$ where $n$ is the sample size, $K$ is the number of histogram intervals, $f_i$ are the frequencies of the intervals and $m_i$ are interval midpoints. That
would amount to the same thing as the method mentioned in the previous
paragraph.

---

*Notes:*

(1) For the question about the table, perhaps see [this related Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777793/using-linear-interpolation-in-statistics/3778080#3778080.)

(2) For the question in the title, sometimes the sample midrange
is a better estimator of the population mean than is the sample
mean. Consider a sample of $n=100$ from a population distributed
$\mathsf{Unif}(10, 20)$ with population mean $\mu = 15.$ In my sample below the sample midrange $15.01$ is closer to $\mu$ than
is the sample mean $\bar X = 14.37.$ (The technical reasons the sample midrange is better in this case than the sample mean are
perhaps best left for another discussion.)

```
set.seed(1234)
u = runif(100, 10, 20)
mean(u);  mean(range(u))
[1] 14.37497
[1] 15.00823
```